# using MPDF malayalam fonts in pdf generation using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

any way to add malayalam font to PDF generation. any methods existing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mPDF supports default malayalam font. after including mpdf folder to third party directory in codeIgniter insert code like

```
 $html = $this->load->view('masterentries/pdfReport',$data,TRUE);
 include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        $pdf = new mPDF('ml', 'A4');

         $pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); 
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
        $pdf->Output();
```

will produce the pdf containing malayalam.